# Generar correos de gmail automáticamente en laravel

Tags: laravel, gmail, g-suite

he estado investigando un poco pero no he encontrado una solución que me resulte, actualmente estoy trabajando con laravel y se presentó la necesidad de creación de correos automáticamente desde el momento en el que se esta registrando a un nuevo usuario, es decir, se registran los datos del usuario y cuando se guarde crear el correo de gmail con una contraseña que seria temporal, para que el usuario ingrese a su correo y la cambie

Si alguien tiene una idea o ha implementado esto anteriormente le agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Gracias. (La institución utiliza actualmente gsuite)

Comment: ¿Cómo vas a garantizar que después de determinado número de creación de cuentas el servicio de gmail no te banee?, te digo eso por que lo puede tomar como comportamiento abusivo

Comment: Por otro lado no se entiende si hablas de solo crear la cadena del correo (*sin verificar disponibilidad*) o si gestionar la creación ante el servicio de gmail con lo cual vuelvo a mi primer comentario

Comment: Finalmente tu pregunta es muy amplia y es casi seguro termine cerrada, trata de mejorarla leyendo [ask]

Comment: bueno eso no lo tenia en cuenta, no conozco bien las políticas de google en ese aspecto, pero pensé que al ser una cuenta de universidad tendría un poco mas de libertad en ese aspecto

Comment: Para no *asumir* te recomiendo mejor repasar las políticas de uso del servicio, si lo prohibe entonces deberás pensar en otra solución sino pues te toca pensar la lógica para *que de ser posible* verifiques la disponibilidad de ese email contra gmail y en concencuencia *de nuevo si es posible* que lo cree en automático, pero de nuevo es algo extenso y te toca pensarle mucho en la lógica

Comment: ok muchas gracias de hecho revisare un poco las políticas para evitar cualquier tipo de inconveniente, ya que es una institución académica

Comment: @HeynerMartinez con cuenta de Gmail, te refieres a una cuenta de G Suite? Me refiero a una cuenta bajo tu dominio. Ejm: `cuenta-nueva@midominio.com`

Comment: exacto de esa forma